# Windows function invalid for 10.1.37-MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, syntax, mariadb, compatibility

Database server version: Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '(partition by post_title order by wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn
> ' at line 8

Query:

```
-- Deleting all duplicate products in wp_posts table

DELETE FROM
wp_posts WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM
(
select ID,post_title,post_type,meta_value from 
(SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id,post_title,post_type ,meta_value,
row_number()over(partition by post_title order by wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn                           
FROM   wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
WHERE  wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' 
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 

) t where t.rn <> 1
) AS aliasx
);

-- Deleting all corresponding wp_postmeta.post_ids that don't have a match in wp_posts.id after the duplicate deletion above

DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (select post_id from (
  SELECT pm.post_id 
  FROM
    wp_postmeta pm
    LEFT JOIN 
    wp_posts p
    ON p.id = pm.post_id
  WHERE
    p.id IS NULL
    AND
    p.post_type = "Product"
) AS aliasy );
```

Could someone suggest a simple code fix that would ensure compatibility to the database version, 10.1.37-MariaDB?

[db Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0e9f20526ceef1e4519959b888a342f1)

Comment: "Windows function invalid for 10.1.37-MariaDB?" Yes [Window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/) work from MariaDB 10.2.0.

Comment: We need example data and expected result to help... [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)... By the way you can simulate `row_number()over(partition ...)` with [user variables](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

Comment: [db Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0e9f20526ceef1e4519959b888a342f1)